# Rails 4 + oauth-plugin for SSO implementation issue

Tags: oauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to install oauth-plugin with rails 4 for sso implemention. But after installation, rails popups following error.

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@monogtest/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib
/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require':
cannot load such file -- action_controller/request (LoadError)
```

logged issue as https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/pull/140

As per the pull request, oauth-plugin is not compatible with rails 4. that's why the pull request is. But pull request doesn't seem to be merged. So what could be the possible solution to this problem.

I will be glad if somebody put some insights.

**update**

Installing gem from https://github.com/tomhughes/oauth-plugin/ works, but which is forked project. How much it is reliable to use such repository which is not from gem author?

Comment: Because it's unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: thanks strawberry for your time. I have added explanation in detail.

Comment: Do I need to add any other info?

Comment: As you know, SO is a fickle place. You only need one more vote to get re-opened so you might get lucky. Wait a little longer.